# How can I get grand total in custom phtml file

Tags: magento-1.9, grand-total

- **Platform**: Magento 1.9
- **Area**: Cart/Quote

I want to get cart **grandtotal** in my custom **phtml** file.

Is there any easy way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple code to fetch grand total anywhere in theme:

```
$grandTotal = Mage::getModel('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getGrandTotal();
```

Comment: That's good, you'r welcome

Comment: Please mark answer as correct if it is helpful to you

Comment: I am unable to mark your answer correct

Comment: Click on the check sign on left side of the answer, it will mark answer as correct :)